# Amazon S3 endpoint is wrong when accessing Asset info

Tags: assets, s3

Amazon S3 is returning the following error for a file in a bucket that is in Ireland (s3-eu-west-1):

> [PermanentRedirect] The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint.

The URL prefix is setup to be s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com, and using the S3.php class standalone with my key/secret, the bucket are listed as being in eu-west-1.

I tried logging out inside S3->getObjectInfo() what endpoint Craft/S3.php was using when accessing the file.

For some reason, it's `s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com`. Isn't that weird?

Answer (score 3):

The problem ended up being that I had completely missed the `location` setting in the database column of the Asset source.